# DesignPattern for Attachments in a Chat with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

User should be able to send some pictures to his chat partner (whatsapp/line style).

There might be a possibility to also add other attachments and videos. We having an argue about the model structure. We are using **carrierwave** to manage the files. right now, the user can only send Pictures, in future there might be some other datatypes to be added.

---

#### Solution 1

pretty standard imo, having 3 classes (each has own DB table) and each class is getting his own carrierwave-uploader.

```
Chat::Picture
Chat::Video
Chat::PDF
```

---

#### Solution 2

this might be a little bit more trickier. Instead of 3 Models we are only having a `Chat::Attachment` and by that we use **STI to define the type**.

```
Chat::Attachment::Picture < Chat::Attachment
Chat::Attachment::Video < Chat::Attachment
Chat::Attachment::Pdf < Chat::Attachment
```

here also every class is getting his own uploader.

---

**So the Question:**: is this the right spot to use STI as a design pattern or should we stick to regular rails-models?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how much change you expect in future. If you expect more changes in future then you should go for rails usual way. I personally dont like STI much. I think you will be better off not using STI here, rails will provide you better separation of concern here. STI should be considered when dealing with model classes that share much of the same functionality and data fields, but you as the developer may want more granular control over extending or adding to each class individually. Rather than duplicate the code over and over for multiple tables (and not being DRY) or forego the flexibility of adding idiosyncratic functionality or methods, STI permits you to use keep your data in a single table while writing specialized functionality.